# How to set range axis values as 0 -100 for StackedbarChart using JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart

I need to develop a Stacked bar chart usinfg JFreeChart that shows values in Percentage and Number. For percentage mode when I am setting range, the values in the range axis changes but the chart gets squished. Please guide me with your valuable suggestions.
Thanks in advance

The code

```
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setRange(0, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown in this variation of [`StackedBarChartDemo2`](http://www.jroller.com/dgilbert/entry/ouch), you should specify (or convert to) percentages in the data model, not in the view. Then you can simply set the range axis label to the percent symbol, `%`.

Comment: In fact, displaying values as percentages is something that can be handled in the view in my opinion, and the StackedBarRenderer class has a flag that lets you switch the display, see the setRenderAsPercentage(boolean) method.